# How to match multiple words in regex

Tags: php, javascript, regex, programming-languages, regex-lookarounds

Just a simple regex I don't know how to write.

The regex has to make sure a string matches all 3 words. I see how to make it match *any* of the 3:

```
/advancedbrain|com_ixxocart|p\=completed/
```

but I need to make sure that *all* 3 words are present in the string.

Here are the words

1. advancebrain
2. com_ixxocart
3. p=completed

Comment: So as an example string you have 'blah blah sample text advancebrain where # com_ixxocart blah blahp=completedstuff' ?

Comment: Personally I'd do this with 3 regexes; it could be pretty ugly as just one, and probably slower.

Comment: Are these from a query string?  If so, you might not need to use any regex

Comment: I have to insert this into one input that google analytics gives me. So, I'm can only use one regex.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*advancebrain)(?=.*com_ixxochart)(?=.*p=completed)
```

will match if all three terms are present.

You might want to add `\b` work boundaries around your search terms to ensure that they are matched as complete words and not substrings of other words (like `advancebraindeath`) if you need to avoid this:

```
^(?=.*\badvancebrain\b)(?=.*\bcom_ixxochart\b)(?=.*\bp=completed\b)
```

Comment: I'm only given an input field to put this regex in, its for google analytics. They show their example of just a simple /yourregex/. Would you guess that lookahead will work? I don't know what programming language they will use to run the regex.

Comment: Looks like GA (Google Analytics) supports lookahead. http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2007/08/08/regular-expressions-for-ga-bonus-iii-lookahead/

Comment: is there a workaround for languages like go which does not support lookahead?

Comment: @klew: You would need to hard-code all the possible permutations, so for a regex that checks if `a`, `b`, and `c` are present in any order, you'd need to search for `a.*b.*c|a.*c.*b|b.*a.*c|b.*c.*a|c.*a.*b|c.*b.*a`.

Comment: This of course is error-prone and scales horribly, so it's probably better to do three separate regex calls, one for each criterion, and make sure that all three match.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(?=.*?p=completed)(?=.*?advancebrain)(?=.*?com_ixxocart).*$
```

Spent too long testing and refining =/ Oh well.. Will still post my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use lookahead:

```
(?=.*\badvancebrain)(?=.*\bcom_ixxocart)(?=.*\bp=completed)
```

Order won't matter. All three are required.

Comment: Better anchor the regex at the start, or you'll get horrible performance if not all three are present.