# Need a regular expression to match multiline String

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression for the multiline string as below

```
Customer:
            VA000347
            VA000347
            Ashu Corp
            Others
            Enterprise

                Mumbai
                5
                Mumbai
                Maharashtra
                232323
                India

        :customer
```

I want to extract the later part i.e. "customer" from the multiline string using regular expression in java and I can match the first part(Customer) literally.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have look at this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421952/how-to-match-multiple-words-in-regex

Comment: this doesn't really help

Comment: what should the output be in your example? just the word :customer ?

Comment: "any help appreciated" --> this doesn't really help .   (ﾉಥ益ಥ）ﾉ ┻━┻

Comment: Jeah would be nice to know what output is expected (question to me is not so clear). To support multiline regex in java use something like this: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("customer", Pattern.MULTILINE);

Answer (score 0):

```
    String text = "Customer:\n"
            + "            VA000347\n"
            + "            VA000347\n"
            + "            Ashu Corp\n"
            + "            Others\n"
            + "            Enterprise\n"
            + "\n"
            + "                Mumbai\n"
            + "                5\n"
            + "                Mumbai\n"
            + "                Maharashtra\n"
            + "                232323\n"
            + "                India\n"
            + "\n"
            + "        :customer";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Customer:\n)(?s)(.*)(?=:customer)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```