# Search Multiple Parameters in String with MongoDB Regex and PHP

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I'm trying to search my collection for all occurrences where the `body` property contains all of the search keywords.

Example string - `"The black cat is definitely purple."`

Keywords `"black", "purple"` would return the string.

Keywords `"black", "dog"` would **not** return that string.

I've been cruising some topics and Googling, but cannot seem to find the proper syntax to do this.

Currently, I am taking an string of keywords separated by commas, exploding it into an array, and then putting that into a `MongoRegex Object`.  I know my syntax is off, because when I send just one keyword it works, but when there is more than one, I do not get any results that I would expect to get.

Current Approach:

```
<?php

function search_topics($array)
{
    include_once('config.php');
    $collection = get_connection($array['flag']);

    $x = 0;
    $string = null;
    $search_results = null;
    $keywords = explode(',', $array['search']); 
    $end_of_list = count($keywords);

    while ($x < $end_of_list)
    {
        $string = $string."/".$keywords[$x];
        $x++;
        if($x >= $end_of_list)
        {
            $string = $string."/i";
        }
    }

    if ($string != null)
    {   
        try
        {
            $regex_obj = new MongoRegex($string);
            $cursor = $collection->find(array('body' => $regex_obj));
        }
        catch (MongoCursorException $e)
        {
            return array('error' => true, 'msg' => $e->getCode());
        }

        foreach($cursor as $post)
        {
            $search_results[] = $post;
        }

        if ($search_results != null && count($search_results) > 1)
        {       
            usort($search_results, 'sort_trending');
        }

        return array('error' => false, 'results' => $search_results);
    }
    else
    {
        return array('error' => false, 'results' => null);
    }
}
?>
```

So, if I send the string `black` in `$array['search']`, my object is formed with `/black/i` and would return that string.

If I send the string `black,cat` in `$array['search']`, my object is formed with `/black/cat/i` and returns `null`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this regex syntax stuff?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Nathan

Comment: Here is some question about matching *all* words: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421952/how-to-match-multiple-words-in-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of regular expressions, I would suggest you look at MongoDB's text search functionality instead, which is specifically made for situations like this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/

You would use that like this (on the MongoDB shell):

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { setParameter: 1, 'textSearchEnabled' : 1 } );
use test
db.so.ensureIndex( { string: 'text' } );
db.so.insert( { string: "The black cat is definitely purple." } );
db.so.runCommand( 'text', { search: '"cat" AND "dog"' } )
db.so.runCommand( 'text', { search: '"cat" AND "purple"' } )
```

A command doesn't return a cursor, but instead it will return one document containing all the query results in the `results` field. For the last search command, the result is:

```
{
    "queryDebugString" : "cat|purpl||||cat|purple||",
    "language" : "english",
    "results" : [
        {
            "score" : 2.25,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("51f8db63c0913ecf728ff4d2"),
                "string" : "The black cat is definitely purple."
            }
        }
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "nscanned" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "n" : 1,
        "nfound" : 1,
        "timeMicros" : 135
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

In PHP, for the `runCommand` to turn on text search, you'd use:

```
$client->database->command( array( 
    'setParameter' => 1, 
    'textSearchEnabled' => 1 
) );
```

And the text search itself as:

```
$client->database->command( array(
    'text' => 'collectionName', 
    'search' => '"cat" AND "purple"' 
) );
```

Comment: This will be used for returning more than one document most of the time.  So, will this approach work since you say it returns one document instead of a cursor?

Comment: Sure, it returns one document, but the ``results`` field of course returns multiple results if the search query finds those.

Comment: Maybe you can help with my latest try and your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984262/no-results-with-text-search-mongodb-php