# No Results with Text Search MongoDB PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to search a text field in my collection.  This is an example document in my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f9c432573906141dbc9996"),
    "id" : ObjectId("51f9c432573906141dbc9995"),
    "body" : "the",
    "rank" : 0,
    "num_comm" : 0,
    "activity" : 1375323186
}
```

This is how I am searching...

```
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1");
$db = $mongo->requestry;

try
{
    $search_results = $db->command(array('text' => 'trending', 'search' => '"the"'));
}
catch (MongoCursorException $e)
{
    return array('error' => true, 'msg' => $e->getCode());
}

return array('error' => false, 'results' => $search_results);
```

And this is the result that I get...

```
{
    error: false,
    results: {
        queryDebugString: "||||the||",
        language: "english",
        results: [ ],
        stats: {
            nscanned: 0,
            nscannedObjects: 0,
            n: 0,
            nfound: 0,
            timeMicros: 66
        },
        ok: 1
    }
}
```

Below are my indexes on the collection...

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "requestry.trending",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "requestry.trending",
    "name" : "body_text",
    "weights" : {
        "body" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 1
}
```

Any ideas on why I get a blank results array every time?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not search for "the" because it is a stop-word, and stop-words are not indexed. You can find a list of stop-words at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt

You can actually see what is being tried to match in the debug string:

```
queryDebugString: "||||the||"
```

The first element is empty here, which means no match is done. If you look what happens for `'"cat" AND "purple"'`, the debug string is:

```
queryDebugString: "cat|purpl||||cat|purple||"
```

The first element(s) are now `cat|purpl` - this shows that stemming has also been applied for `purple`.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested quotes on your code ('the' string literal):

```
$search_results = $db->command(array('text' => 'trending', 'search' => '"the"'));
```

Try not nesting the quotes

```
$search_results = $db->command(array('text' => 'trending', 'search' => 'the'));
```

Comment: I believe `'"the"'` is valid FTS syntax

Comment: Syntax is fine.  If you were looking in the PHP Manual, the syntax is wrong in there.